# Assign a value in scatterplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to assign to a specific value, a color, while comparing different clustering techniques with n clusters, in this case 3:

```
print(data2D)

x       y      k_label        h_label
10      5        0               1
8       5        1               1
...

#1
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
#plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c=kmeans.labels_.astype(float))
#sns.scatterplot(x=data2D[:,0], y= data2D[:,1], data=data2D)
plt.title("K-MEANS")
#2
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c= agg_h.labels_.astype(float))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title("AGGLOMERATIVE HIERARCHICAL CLUSTERING")
plt.show()
```

I tried with:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(data= {'h_label': np.unique(df.k_label), 'k_label': np.unique(df.k_label), "color": ["red", "blue", "yellow"] })

df = df.merge(temp, on = ["h_label"])
df["k_label"] = kmeans.predict(X)
```

But it seems redoundant and I don't know how to implement it in Matplotlib.

Briefly, I would like to plot, side by side, two figures in which clusters (k_label & h_label) = 1 are equal to red, =2 blue ... n = last color etc.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this:
same colormap for both plot?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this command assigns a signle color to each cluster value?

Comment: yes, see all the 0s have got green color in both the plots and 1s and 2s also have same color in both.